# setting environment variables in Powershell: persistence issue

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I am looking for a way to have things like environment variables persist from one `Powershell` command to the next. Specifically, I have 3 commands that work in a command prompt, but not in `Powershell`. The commands are

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"

cmake -G "Ninja" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-v0.3.10\OpenBLAS-0.3.10\out\install\x64-Release" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=cl -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=ninja "C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-v0.3.10\OpenBLAS-0.3.10" >cmakeOut.txt

cmake --build "C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-v0.3.10\OpenBLAS-0.3.10" >cmakeBuildOut.txt
```

You can see that I want to build (compile and link) a package called openBLAS (basic linear algebra system). I already have a Powershell script that can download and unpack the openblas package, and I want to use this script as part of Travis CI. In Powershell, the commands look like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {&"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat";Get-Item -Path Env:INCLUDE}
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {cmake -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-v0.3.10\OpenBLAS-0.3.10\out\install\x64-Release" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=cl -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=ninja "C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-v0.3.10\OpenBLAS-0.3.10"}
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {cmake --build "C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-v0.3.10\OpenBLAS-0.3.10"}
```

You can see that I have put a `Get-Item` command into the first script block. This is because the first command, `vcvars64.bat`, creates a number of environment variables, including `INCLUDE`, that are needed later. However, the `Get-Item` shows that the `INCLUDE` variable does not exist, even though it was just created. This probably has something to do with environment variables that only persist for a Windows session, and each `Invoke-Command` being a separate session, but putting everything into a single script block didn't solve the problem. Now, I have found another way to set environment variables in Powershell, using `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable`, but I am not setting the variables myself, rather calling `vcvars64.bat`.

So what I am looking for is a way to make the results of vcvars64.bat persist into the following commands, maybe by making all of the Powershell commands part of one Windows session. I tried adding the option `-NoNewScope` to each `Invoke-Command`, but that didn't help either.

Comment: I think environment variables are not available in the shell they are created. It may be best to run your scripts that create the variables first. Then run subsequent `Invoke-Command`s after to utilize their contents.

Comment: environment Vars are _per-session_ unless you force them to be persistent. the `I-C` call is making a new session, setting the EV there, and then exiting that session ... which erases the session settings - including the EV items. SOLUTIONS - [1] don't use `I-C`. [*grin*] run the commands in the same session that is calling them. [2] create _persistent_ EV items with `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` and use the appropriate scope [machine, user, process].

Comment: [2] Since the environment variables are created by vcvars64.bat, I don't see a way to tell that batch file to create persistent EV items.

Comment: [1] Run the commands in the same session, OK, that means not using Invoke-Command, so I can only see that as using a batch file instead of a Powershell script. Is that the final recommendation?